# Web scraping issue while scraping from one table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/ap-govt-jobs/144586/')
c = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
row = soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all('tr')
dict = {}
for i in row:
    for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={'style':'color: #008000;'}):
        dict['Title'] = title.text
    for link in i.find_all('a',title=True, href=True):
        dict['Link'] = link['href']
        print(dict)
```

Here i am getting empty data:

I am expecting:

```
{'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Detailed-Notification-Directorate-of-Public-Health-Family-Welfare-Vijayawada-Civil-Assistant-Surgeon-Posts.pdf', 'Title': 'Detailed Notification'}
{'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Notification-Directorate-of-Public-Health-Family-Welfare-Vijayawada-Civil-Assistant-Surgeon-Posts.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '}
{'Link': 'http://cfw.ap.nic.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}
```

Here i am scraping data from only first table. but it is giving me data from all the tables..
I want only important links from first table. but it is giving me both.
please have a look into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it runs fine for me but I changed the name dict to some_dict like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/ap-govt-jobs/144586/')
c = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
row = soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all('tr')
some_dict = {}
for i in row:
    for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={'style': 'color: #008000;'}):
        some_dict['Title'] = title.text
    for link in i.find_all('a', title=True, href=True):
        some_dict['Link'] = link['href']
        print(some_dict)
```

As it shadows Python's built in dict class.
My output is:

```
{'Title': 'Detailed Notification', 'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Detailed-Notification-Directorate-of-Public-Health-Family-Welfare-Vijayawada-Civil-Assistant-Surgeon-Posts.pdf'}
{'Title': 'Notification ', 'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Notification-Directorate-of-Public-Health-Family-Welfare-Vijayawada-Civil-Assistant-Surgeon-Posts.pdf'}
{'Title': ' Official Website', 'Link': 'http://cfw.ap.nic.in/'}
```

If you rename dict to something else, does it run?